# Primary Key Problem ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I am developing a career website for one of my projects. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET Web Forms to code.

My problem is I have got a table named `Companies` which consists of columns `Company ID, Company Name, Company Address` and `Company Phone`. `CompanyID` is my primary key. I am trying to insert new companies to this table using Linq-to-SQL.

When I execute the following piece of code, if the database is empty, the code works properly but if it is not it can't auto increment the `CompanyID` and gives me a database error.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label_error.Text = "";
    Page.Validate();

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        CareerDataContext db = new CareerDataContext();

        Company newCompany = new Company { coName = TextBox_coName.Text, coAddress = TextBox_coAddress.Text, coPhone = int.Parse(TextBox_coPhone.Text) };
        Company fCompany = db.Companies.SingleOrDefault(company => company.coName.Equals(TextBox_coName.Text));

        if (fCompany == null)
        {
            db.Companies.InsertOnSubmit(newCompany);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        else
            Label_error.Text = "This username is already in use";
    }
}
```

Comment: **WHAT** error do you get (exactly) ?? And what datatype is your `CompanyID` on your database??

Comment: And what does your problem have to do with ASP.NET? How would the problem be different if you were using a Console program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CompanyID is a uniqueidentifier then you can pass in `Guid.NewGuid()`;

For example:

```
Company newCompany = new Company { coID = Guid.NewGuid(), coName = TextBox_coName.Text, coAddress = TextBox_coAddress.Text, coPhone = int.Parse(TextBox_coPhone.Text) };
```

Comment: I didn't understand your point. How should I use Guid.NewGuid(); ?

Comment: Solved. I recreate my DBML and fixed. Interesting but solved =)